# How to find out the commuting set in this problem

Tags: matrices

I was going through the Herstein"s exercise of ring theory(first chapter).There i encountered a problem which tells us to find the set of all those square matrices of order 2 over real field that commutes with every square matrices of order 2 over real field with respect usual matrix multplication of real matrices.

Now ,i have given an attempt in a very normal way ,i.e taken a matrix A from the commuting set and a matrix B from the set of all matrix of order 2 arbitrarily(i haven written matrices explicitly with elements a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h from real field) but the process seems to be tedious and inconclusive at a moments glance.Also cannot leave the problem as the question seems to be very prime and original question to the study of set of all real matrices of order 2 over real field.

Any comprehensive help from any end is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Since $A$ has to commute with every matrix $B$, so start with an elementary matrix for $B$. For example,
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$
This will give you some ideas about how some entries of $A$ will look like. Then try with another elementary matrix and so on.